Relation between $L$-Lipschitz continuity and sequential weak continuity.
Def1: Let $A:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous operator, where $\mathcal{H}$ is real Hilbert space, if for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$, $\|Ax-Ay\| \leq L \|x-y\|$. Here $L>0$ is the Lipschitz constant greater than zero.
Def2: An operator ($A$, same as defined above) is sequentially weakly continuous on $\mathcal{H}$, if for any sequence $\{x_{n}\} \in \mathcal{H}$, $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$, implies $Ax_{n} \rightharpoonup Ax$.
Can we say that Def1 implies Def2.

A few clarifications on your notation... 1) is $\mathcal H$ the same as $H$? 2) Def1 does not seem to be a definition. Did you mean to provide the definition of being $L$-Lipschitz continuous there?

Yes, both are the same $\mathcal{H}$. Sorry for the mistake. I have updated the question.


If by operator you mean a linear operator, then the answer is yes: $1\Rightarrow 2.$ Assume $A$ is a continuous linear operator (equivalent to Lipschitz), then
its adjoint $A^*$ is continuous as well. Thus, given $x_n$ converging weakly to $x$ we have, for any $y\in \mathcal H$

$$\lim \langle Ax_n,y\rangle=\lim \langle x_n,A^* y\rangle=\langle x,A^*y\rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle,$$
which proves that $Ax_n$ converges weakly to $Ax$.

If you do not require $A$ to be linear, the result is false. Indeed, let
$A:L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ be defined as
$$A f=f\chi_{f>0}.$$

We claim that $A$ is Lipschitz continuous, which is proved as follows:
$$\|Af-Ag\|^2=\int |f\chi_{f>0}-g\chi_{g>0}|^2
\le \int_{f>0, g>0} |f-g|^2+\int_{f>0,g\le 0}|f|^2+\int_{f\le 0,g>0} |g|^2\le 3\int |f-g|^2.$$
To prove that $A$ is not weak sequentially continuous, consider $f_n(x)=\sin(2\pi n x)$, which converges weakly to $0$. However,
$$\langle Af_n,1\rangle=\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi n x)\chi_{f_n>0}=\frac12\int_0^1 |\sin(2\pi n x)|=\frac1\pi\not\to 0=\langle A 0,1\rangle$$

I suggest you look up Young measures, a formal "quantitative"" way of measuring how much continuity is not enough to ensure weak continuity
